# Syntax to combine the COUNTIF and MID functions in Excel

Tags: excel, syntax, syntax-error

Would any body be able to advise me on the correct syntax for using the COUNTIF and MID functions simultaneously in Excel. My current attempt is as follows:

```
=COUNTIF(MID(A1:A6,1,1),"1")
```

I'm attempting to count the number of strings in a list with integer 1 as the first character.

Any help offered would be greatly appreciated.

Thanking you in advance,

Jared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A6,"1*")
```

or if you are using excel 2007 or later

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:A6,"1*")
```

Note that this will match *strings* but not *numbers*

**Update:**

to count strings beginning with integers >1 try

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:A6,"2*")+COUNTIFS(A1:A6,"3*")+COUNTIFS(A1:A6,"4*")+COUNTIFS(A1:A6,"5*")+COUNTIFS(A1:A6,"6*")+COUNTIFS(A1:A6,"7*")+COUNTIFS(A1:A6,"8*")+COUNTIFS(A1:A6,"9*")
```

A bit clunky I know, but it's all I can think of for now

Comment: Sorry to bother you again but is it possible to edit this statement to count the number values starting with integers > 1?